# Quick way to clear all classes and triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata

Long story, but I want to clear all the code from an org. I don't need to clear Visualforce pages (there is only one, and I'm deleting that manually) - just all triggers and Apex classes. Does anyone have a quick way to do it?

I have a feeling that it will involve using Workbench, but I've never tried it so I'm coming here before doing anything with that.

Using the UI and deleting triggers and classes one by one is not an option.

Comment: If you want to keep VF pages you may want to specify how you want to deal with classes that are VF controllers, or classes that are used from VF controllers.

Comment: Done. Good idea. I have only one page, which I'm deleting manually. No need to overcomplicate this ugly process!

Comment: btw: my guess is on the tooling api, but I don't know it well enough to shape that into an answer.

Comment: Do you have any Force.com Sites set up in the org @DavidSchach?

Comment: No sites. It is a pretty sparse org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way using just the Salesforce-supported tool and no dependencies. Proceed with caution ;-)

1. create a temporary directory to work in,
2. download [salesforce_ant_29.0.zip](https://login.salesforce.com/dwnld/SfdcAnt/salesforce_ant_29.0.zip) and extract into a subdirectory `lib/salesforce_ant_29.0`
3. create a file in your temp directory called **build.properties** containing the following:

   ```
   sf.username=username@example.com
   sf.password=passwordandsecuritytoken
   ```
4. create another file in the temp directory called **build.xml**, then `cd` in there and  run `ant purge`:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <project name="buildSystem" default="deploy" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
>
>     <taskdef uri="antlib:com.salesforce"
>                  resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml"
>                  classpath="${basedir}/lib/salesforce_ant_29.0/ant-salesforce.jar"/>
>     <property file="build.properties"/>
>     <property environment="env"/>
>
>     <target name="purge" description="PURGE TRIGGERS AND CLASSES">
>         <!-- Clean up any previous purge -->
>         <delete dir="purge" />
>         <mkdir dir="purge" />
>
>         <!-- Prepare a wildcard package definition with as many metadata types as possible -->
>         <echo file="purge/package.xml"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>             <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>                 <types><members>*</members><name>ApexClass</name></types>
>                 <types><members>*</members><name>ApexTrigger</name></types>
>                 <version>29.0</version>
>             </Package>
>         ]]></echo>
>
>         <!-- Retrieve the wildcard package definition -->
>         <sf:retrieve
>         username="${sf.username}"
>         password="${sf.password}"
>         serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
>         retrieveTarget="purge"
>         unpackaged="purge/package.xml"
>         pollWaitMillis="1000" />
>
>         <!-- Name the package definition -->
>         <replace file="purge/package.xml">
>             <replacetoken><![CDATA[</version>]]></replacetoken>
>             <replacevalue><![CDATA[</version><fullName>Purge</fullName>]]></replacevalue>
>         </replace>
>
>         <!-- Re-deploy the now-named wildcard package definition -->
>         <sf:deploy
>         username="${sf.username}"
>         password="${sf.password}"
>         serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
>         deployRoot="purge"
>         purgeOnDelete="true"
>         pollWaitMillis="1000" />
>
>         <!-- Retrieve by name, giving us an explicit package definition -->
>         <sf:retrieve
>         username="${sf.username}"
>         password="${sf.password}"
>         serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
>         retrieveTarget="purge"
>         packageNames="Purge"
>         pollWaitMillis="1000" />
>
>         <!--
>          ! Trash local components: we only needed them to get an explicit package definition.
>          ! Now we turn the explicit package definition into explicit destructive changes, and
>          ! blank out the package definition.
>          !-->
>         <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" dir="purge" includes="**/*" excludes="*.xml" />
>         <copy file="purge/package.xml" tofile="purge/destructiveChanges.xml" />
>         <echo file="purge/package.xml"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>             <Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
>                 <version>29.0</version>
>             </Package>
>         ]]></echo>
>
>         <!-- Perform explicit deploy over the top of the org which should delete all components -->
>         <sf:deploy
>         username="${sf.username}"
>         password="${sf.password}"
>         serverurl="https://login.salesforce.com"
>         deployRoot="purge"
>         purgeOnDelete="true"
>         pollWaitMillis="1000" />
>
>         <!-- Tidy up after ourselves -->
>         <delete dir="purge" />
>     </target>
> </project>
> ```

Answer (score 3):

FinancialForce open sourced a tool we use internally to undeploy *everything* from an org. You need to invoke it via ant, and it goes above and beyond your needs (also removing objects, static resources, etc). I suspect it's your best bet here.

https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-deployment-tools

Answer (score 1):

Using Eclipse to delete classes by one time.